# How do I make an element's positioning fixed, yet still slide in/out?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, panel

I'm trying to make a simple responsive web page that turns a horizontal menu navigation into a slide-in side panel for mobile devices. I've made a lot of progress, but I'm not sure how to keep the tab trigger visible at all times (on narrow screens). If I set the positioning to "fixed", then the tab trigger doesn't slide with the panel. If I set it to "absolute", then the tab trigger scrolls off the screen.

Here's the page: http://www.toprival.com/temp/side_menu/side_menu1.html

Comment: I tested this out in Chrome. If I just switch it to `position:fixed`, it seems to work exactly as intended. What are you using to test?

Comment: I did the same thing Alex, it seems fine.

Comment: Yeah... seems to work fine for me when using `position: fixed`. Maybe he's talking on how fixed positioning via css doesn't work (consistently, at least) on mobile devices? **Need more information from you, Kris.**

Comment: I'm sorry... it does seem to be working as you said. Yesterday the tab trigger was staying put while the panel slid in behind it. Not sure what the problem was. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that with these jQuery function you are ok!

Try it out!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function controlMobile() {
    var mobile = $(window).width();
    if(mobile</*SET YOUR OPTION IN PX*/){
    $('#panel').css({ 
      'position': 'fixed'
    });
    }else{
      $('#panel').css({ 
        'position': 'static'
      });
    }
  }

$(window).on('resize', function() { controlMobile(); });
  controlMobile();
});
```

Comment: All that's going to do is what I'm already doing with CSS media queries, and it doesn't solve the problem at all.